# Next.js: Error EBADF: bad file descriptor error

Tags: next.js, mern, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing, nextjs-storybook

I have freshly installed Next.js and followed all instructions but it is not working properly. When I try to run my project I get the following error:

```
node:fs:453
    return binding.readFileUtf8(path, stringToFlags(options.flag));
                   ^

Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, read
```

Comment: You can find this [exact issue on github](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues/3338). Please note that stack overflow expects you to do a [certain degree of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593) yourself before posting a question. A simple google search surely would have sufficed.